# Need help escaping password in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have password that looks like this `KMqJH9OL?LoNw:w=ZgD1;?zLrH<c`. Now when I am trying to input this password into the groovy script it breaks because of `;` and `<`.

I have tried different ways to escape this non of it worked. In the below code `BITBUCKET_PASS` is the one having the above password.

```
sh '''
   yarn cov-report -c ${BUILD_VERSION} -u ${BITBUCKET_USER} -p ${BITBUCKET_PASS} $PWD/backend/test_report/lcov.info
'''
```

Here's the code that I have tried and it didn't work.

```
sh '''
   yarn cov-report -c ${BUILD_VERSION} -u ${BITBUCKET_USER} -p "${BITBUCKET_PASS}" $PWD/backend/test_report/lcov.info
'''
```

Comment: So when the sh command starts running, that is when the error comes?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find a way to escape ```BITBUCKET_PASS ``` in the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the [String interpolation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables) in Groovy scripts :

Instead using `{}` try like this :

```
sh '''
   yarn cov-report -c $BUILD_VERSION -u $BITBUCKET_USER -p $BITBUCKET_PASS $PWD/backend/test_report/lcov.info
'''
```